# Listview crashes in portrait mode when clicked on items (using fragments)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I am using fragment layout in my app, this app contains a listview. Clicking on items will do some job. works fine when in landscape mode but getting crashed if items are clicked when in portait mode. What can be the problem?

Here is my code:

**MainAcitivity.java**

```
package com.example.newfragment;

import android.content.res.Configuration;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        /*/ Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toast.makeText(this, "portait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/


    }



}
```

**MenuFragment.java** *// showing the list view*

```
    package com.example.newfragment;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    int i; 

    private String[] FilePathStrings;
    private String[] FileNameStrings;
     File[] listFile;//for photo
    String[] name = new String[] 
            { "Sri","Sud","Urmila","Amrita","Indra","Ayan",
            "Leo","Neymar","Robin","Ian","Suarez","Mesut","Bastin",
            "Rooney","Ranti","Dong Hyun","Barisich","Andrew" };

    String[] address = new String[]
            {"Dumdum","Dumdum","Dumdum","Dumdum","Lake Town",
            "Salkia","Argentina","Brazil","Netherlands"};

    String [] mobile = new String[]{"456456456","56564565","787687866",
                "645645645","5654576457","76897978978","768768567"};



    String [] photo = new String[]{};



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return view;





    }



    /////////////////////sending data to TextFragment//////////////////
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


        ///////////accessing files from sd card///////
         File file = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/");
         if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();

            // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
            FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];


            for (i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                // Get the path of the image file
                FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();

            }
        }

       //////////////////////////////


        TextFragment txt = (TextFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        txt.change(position,address[position],mobile[position]);
        getListView().setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);


    }
}
```

**TextFragment.java** *// for the actions upon clicking the items*

```
  package com.example.newfragment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.R.string;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TextFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    TextView text,add;
    private ImageView img;
    Button b;
    int value;
    String mobile;
    File photo;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    Camera camera;


    ////////////data received here////////////
    public void change(int txt, String txt1, String txt2 ){


        add.setText(txt1 );
        value = txt;
        mobile = txt2;

        //photo = f;
        //File image = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg"); 

        /*if(photo.exists())
        {
            img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
        else
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);*/

    }

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container, false);
        //text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.AndroidOs);
        add= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address);
        img= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);

        //////////////////
        /*File image = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg"); 
        if(image.exists())
            {

                     img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));/////////////setting image in imageview
            }*/


        //////////////////////
        b= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.b);

        img.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);



        return view;

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.equals(img))
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            /*///////////camera hardware///////////
            Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();//////////////PROBLEM: APP GETTING CRASHED WHEN USED
            parameters.setPictureSize(80, 80);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera = Camera.open();
            ///////////////////////////////////////*/



            /*Clicking and saving image to sd card*/
            //////////////////////////////////////
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Frag_list");
            file.mkdirs();

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg";
            File file2= new File(path);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file2 );
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
            //intent.putExtra("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE", outputFileUri ); ///////for displaying image
            intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri ); //////////for saving image

            /*Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE", outputFileUri);*/

            startActivityForResult( intent, CAMERA_REQUEST );
            /////////////////////////////////////



        }

        if(v.equals(b))
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "mobile:"+mobile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            /*Calling number*/
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" +mobile);
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
            startActivity(callIntent);
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        }

    }

    ///setting image in display
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
            {  
                /*if (data != null) {


                    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg");  

                    Uri imgUri=Uri.fromFile(photo);
                    img.setImageURI(imgUri);

                    /*
                    img.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")); // this is image view where you want to set image
                    Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));

                }*/

                File image = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg"); 
                if(image.exists()){

                         img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));/////////////setting image in imageview
            }

            }


        }
     ////////////////////*/


}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newfragment"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"  android:required="false" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation" 
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat**

```
    10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at com.example.newfragment.TextFragment.change(TextFragment.java:48)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at com.example.newfragment.MenuFragment.onListItemClick(MenuFragment.java:85)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2815)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3574)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-05 11:07:06.480: E/AndroidRuntime(4921):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_Fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.newfragment.MenuFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ActivityMain.xml** *of landscpae*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.newfragment.MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.newfragment.MenuFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment"/>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        class="com.example.newfragment.TextFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

**ListFragment.xml** *// for the listview*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**TextFragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#5ba4e5"
    >
    <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:onClick="imageClick"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:text="Mobile"

                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshots**

[image: image of app in landscape mode, after clicking an item from the list]

> Current situation of the portait mode after following the suggestions suggested in the answers:

[image: image of app in portait mode, after clicking an item from the list]

**UPDATE**

I am **able to overcome the crashing problem and to move to next screen after clicking on items** from the listview while in **portait mode** currently, but the view is returning null there; means the contents which I want to be displayed there **(blue part of the screenshot) is not displaying**, the **screen is blank**.

Here is the updated code:

**MenuFragment.java**

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {

    int i; 

    private String[] FilePathStrings;
    private String[] FileNameStrings;
     File[] listFile;//for photo
    String[] name = new String[] 
            { "Sri","Sud","Urmila","Amrita","Indra","Ayan",
            "Leo","Neymar","Robin","Ian","Suarez","Mesut","Bastin",
            "Rooney","Ranti","Dong Hyun","Barisich","Andrew" };

    String[] address = new String[]
            {"Dumdum","Dumdum","Dumdum","Dumdum","Lake Town",
            "Salkia","Argentina","Brazil","Netherlands"};

    String [] mobile = new String[]{"456456456","56564565","787687866",
                "645645645","5654576457","76897978978","768768567"};



    String [] photo = new String[]{};



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name);
        setListAdapter(adapter);



        return view;


    }





    /////////////////////sending data to TextFragment//////////////////
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

///////////accessing files from sd card///////
         File file = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/");
         if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();

            // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
            FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];


            for (i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                // Get the path of the image file
                FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();

            }
        }

         //////////////////////////////


        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
        if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) { 
            //Do SomeThing; // Landscape




            TextFragment txt = (TextFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
            txt.change(position,address[position],mobile[position]);
            getListView().setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

        } else { 
            //Do SomeThing;  // Portrait
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(),address[position] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

*//////////////updated code here///////////////*

```
        **Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TextFragment2.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", address[position]);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);**





}

}
```

}

**TextFragment.java**

```
public class TextFragment2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView text,add;
    private ImageView img;
    Button b;
    int value;
    String mobile,txt;
    File photo;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    Camera camera;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container, false);

        add= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address);
        img= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);

        //////////////////
        /*File image = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg"); 
        if(image.exists())
            {

                     img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));/////////////setting image in imageview
            }*/


        //////////////////////
        b= (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.b);

        img.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        //String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

*/////////////////////updated code here////////////////*

**Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
        txt= bundle.getString("message");**

```
    **add.setText(txt);**

    return view;

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.equals(img))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        /*///////////camera hardware///////////
        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();//////////////PROBLEM: APP GETTING CRASHED WHEN USED
        parameters.setPictureSize(80, 80);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera = Camera.open();
        ///////////////////////////////////////*/



        /*Clicking and saving image to sd card*/
        //////////////////////////////////////
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Frag_list");
        file.mkdirs();

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg";
        File file2= new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file2 );
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        //intent.putExtra("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE", outputFileUri ); ///////for displaying image
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri ); //////////for saving image

        /*Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE", outputFileUri);*/

        startActivityForResult( intent, CAMERA_REQUEST );
        /////////////////////////////////////



    }

    if(v.equals(b))
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "mobile:"+mobile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*Calling number*/
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" +mobile);
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);
        startActivity(callIntent);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }

}

///setting image in display
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {  
            /*if (data != null) {


                File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg");  

                Uri imgUri=Uri.fromFile(photo);
                img.setImageURI(imgUri);

                /*
                img.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data")); // this is image view where you want to set image
                Log.d("camera ---- > ", "" + data.getExtras().get("data"));

            }*/

            File image = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Frag_list/"+value+".jpg"); 
            if(image.exists()){

                     img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath()));/////////////setting image in imageview
        }

        }


    }
 ////////////////////*/
```

}

---

**CASE SOLVED**

Changed the public View oncreateView to protected void onCreate! :)

```
public class TextFragment2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView text,add;
    private ImageView img;
    Button b;
    int value;
    String mobile,txt;
    File photo;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    Camera camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text_fragment);

        add= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.b);

        img.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
        txt= bundle.getString("message");
        add.setText(txt);

    }
```

Screenshots of portrait mode:

[image: after clicking item "Sri" from the list]

Comment: can you post your logcat ?

Comment: Ok I'm editing and adding the logcat

Comment: May i know why it received a negative vote? I have explained properly what I meant to say.

Comment: your initial orientation is landscape ? you getting null exception means that you loosing the reference of this TextFragment

Comment: No. But when I rotate it to landscape mode, it works absolutely fine.

Comment: its a .NullPointerException , may be your portal adapter xml dot have the ids

Comment: is the layout's content is different for land and portrait mode ?

Comment: So what I should I do about that? @Sree

Comment: so you should double check all the id for your portal and landscape are same as you said in your adapter

Comment: if the ids are different for both than you have to check for the portrait & land mode and work accordingly

Comment: When in landscape mode, on clicking the items will move to a fragment within the same screen, but when in portait mode, it will display to another screen

Comment: in your case simply its not getting the ids

Comment: TextFragment of Landscape ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TextFragment2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView text,add;
    private ImageView img;
    Button b;
    int value;
    String mobile,txt;
    File photo;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    Camera camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text_fragment);

        add= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.b);

        img.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
        txt= bundle.getString("message");
        add.setText(txt);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method `change` that is trying to use a `TextView add` which is having a null reference. Kindly initialize it before using it.

This is what is the root cause of the problem:

```
add.setText(txt1);
```

Here, add is pointing to null, and you are using that null reference.

Another point of problem seems in the id ie `fragment2` of `fragment` in `ActivityMain.xml` layout, as mentioned by @Syed Nazar Muhammad. Thanks for that.

```
TextFragment txt = (TextFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

`R.id.fragment2` is missing in `ActivityMain.xml`

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: That code is working fine when in landscape. It is displaying the address related to item clicked on the list. It that was null, the app should have crashed in landscape mode too

Comment: @Stack Overflowerrr did you checked his layouts

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
TextFragment txt = (TextFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
```

you are trying to find the R.id.fragment2 which is only in landscape layout of MainActivity, when you rotate to landscape it finds the id fragment2, but when you rotate the device to portrait mode the id is not found as it is not there in the portrait mode of the MainActivity.

Comment: So should I mention fragment2 in the activitymain.xml for portait mode too?

Comment: in portrait mode when click on list you don't want to open the fragment as it was in MainActivity of landscape ? if the procedure is same as of landscape then just add the fragment2 in the MainActivity's Portrait layout too

Comment: adding fragment2 in the activitymain prevents the crash but on clicking the items I cannot move to next screen, where the actions are displayed... And a block of blank spaces showing below of the list

Comment: OR if after onclick of listview you want to be on the TextFragment's layout then you have to add fragment2 in your TextFragment layout

Comment: I have added a screenshot of landscape mode. The blue part on the right side is the textfragment. I want that part to be viewed in another screen after clicking the items when in portait mode(like how we do it using intents).. not in the same like in landscape

Comment: make a new fragment for Portrait mode Similar to that blue part & check the orientation in you code if its portait while clicking on the listview open this brand new fragment with its inividual layout

Comment: Done that. Nothing different happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91353/discussion-between-syed-nazar-muhammad-and-sri).